# Can't read objects from file and place them to linkedlist in java

Tags: java, file

I want to read object from a file and place data to a `LinkedList` and return the reference to it. But when I try this method it returns LinkedList that have no data.

```
private static LinkedList<Course> readFromFile(String fileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    LinkedList<Course> tmp = new LinkedList<Course>();

    reader = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));

    try {
        LinkedList<Course> readObject2 = (LinkedList<Course>) reader
                .readObject();
        LinkedList<Course> readObject = readObject2;
        tmp = readObject;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

My writing method looks like this

```
private static boolean writeToFile(String fileName, LinkedList<Course> templist)
        throws IOException {
    LinkedList<Course> templist1 = new LinkedList<Course>();

    if (createFile(fileName)) {
        FileOutputStream outF = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

        outO = new ObjectOutputStream(outF);
        outO.writeObject(templist1);

        //outO.flush();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

---

Writing method looks like this

```
private static boolean writeToFile(String fileName, LinkedList<Course> templist) throws IOException {
    LinkedList<Course> templist1 = new LinkedList<Course>();

    if (createFile(fileName)) {
        FileOutputStream outF = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

        outO = new ObjectOutputStream(outF);
        outO.writeObject(templist1);

        //outO.flush();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Does your file has list of objects stored in it?

Comment: How did you serialize your `Course`s? Did you serialize entire list `writeObject(LinkedListOfCourses)` or did you serialize each course separately `writeObject(Course1), ...,  writeObject(CourseX)`.

Comment: To update your question with more details use [[edit]] option placed under your post.

Answer (score 1):

The Course class is implementing [java.io.Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) ?
When you read objects from a file with **ObjectInputStream** it should be in the same order that you stored it with ObjectOutputStream before. And with the same objects types.

If you try to read:

```
 (LinkedList<Course>) reader.readObject();
```

You must have store it like:

```
ObjectOutputStream writer = new ObjectOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(fileName));

writer.writeObject(yourLinkedListToSave);
```

As your code looks:

```
private static boolean writeToFile(String fileName, LinkedList<Course> templist) throws IOException {
    // Dont forget to initialize with your list else the list still empty
    LinkedList<Course> templist1 = new LinkedList<Course>(templist);

    if (createFile(fileName)) {
        FileOutputStream outF = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

        outO = new ObjectOutputStream(outF);
        outO.writeObject(templist1);

        //outO.flush();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: write method is like that and i think it stores like what you wanted

private static boolean writeToFile(String fileName, LinkedList<Course> templist) throws IOException{
  
  LinkedList<Course> templist1 = new LinkedList<Course>();

  
  if(createFile(fileName)){
   
   FileOutputStream outF = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
         outO = new ObjectOutputStream(outF);
         outO.writeObject(templist1);
         //outO.flush();
   return true;
  }
  
  else
   return false;
     }

Comment: Use `LinkedList<Course> templist1 = new LinkedList<Course>(templist);` else the LinkedList that you are storing still empty.

Comment: thanks it helped me so much and solved problem. problem was the thing that you mentioned.

Comment: ++ since you found problem, but I am just wondering why we even need second `templist1`. We can skip it and just `writeObject(templist)` passed as `writeToFile` method argument. Also in `readFromFile` method `LinkedList<Course> readObject = readObject2;` doesn't look good, we can simply use `tmp = (LinkedList<Course>) reader.readObject();`, or even `return (LinkedList<Course>) reader.readObject();` so we don't even need `tmp` variable.

Comment: @Pshemo You are right. But the code was like this :) Maybe there is some concurrent access on it for example. It's a good behaviour to use copy on **List** in this case.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the case, since this kind of copy will not help us much because concurrent change can occur while copying.